# Android VideoRecording error, cannot create path to file

Tags: java, android

java.lang.IOException, path to file cannot be created. my catch is working by dont know why is isnt being created?

Im not sure why im getting this error, i assumed the setOutputFile() would create the file ..

any help appreciated, as there are a few errors in DDMS

this is my viderecorder class:

```
    package com.sg86.quickrecord;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import android.media.MediaRecorder;
    import android.os.Environment;

    public class VideoRecorder {

  final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
     final String path;

     /**
     * create a new video recording stored in SDcard Root
     */
 public VideoRecorder(String path) {
     this.path = organisePath(path);
     }

 private String organisePath(String path) {
  if (!path.startsWith("/")) {
   path = "/" + path;
     }
     if (!path.contains(".")) {
      path += ".3gp";
     }
     return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + path;
     } 
    public void start() throws IOException {
     String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if(!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))  {
            throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state + ".");
        }

        // make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
        File directory = new File(path).getParentFile();
        if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
          throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
        }
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        recorder.setOutputFile(path);
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    }
    public void stop() throws IOException {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
    }
 }
```

**this is my main activity**

```
package com.sg86.quickrecord;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.IllegalStateException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class QuickRecord extends Activity {

 public static final String WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button recordBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button01);
        Button stopBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button02);
        final VideoRecorder record = new VideoRecorder("/QuickRecord/recording");

        recordBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
     record.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  });

        stopBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   
   public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
     record.stop();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

See [Security and Permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html) for more details.

Comment: i added this to the .java file

public static final String WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

lol, very noob i know but the android resources arent very clear at all!

eclipse shows no proposals in the manifest which is a shame. that fixed that error thankyou! got a bunch of others now.

i changed it about to record audio insted, added all the permissions and hardware features to the manifest and got it to record a clip to the right location! 

could the video issue be down to lack of a preview in my app? the error relates to SurfaceView so i assume so

Comment: @Shaun: If you have another problem, post a separate question with the description of the error you are getting.

Comment: thankyou mate, ill work on it tomorrow, i was just playing with appwidget, how horrible is that!